# The best user manager extension for yii?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

What is the best user manager for yii in your opinion? On irc i heard yii-auth?

I need 2 types of users:
1) workers - they have limited access to diffrent panels.
2) clients - they have access to shops to buy products and some very limited other places.

Can i use module like yii-auth to 1) and 2)? Or it have sense only to 1)?

The application what i am writing is the shop with many with full complex funcionality like support etc.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something simple, at authentication time, set in the SESSION the type of the user.

```
// Example
Yii::app()->user->setState('type', 'W'); // Worker
Yii::app()->user->setState('type', 'C'); // Client
```

And then, before performing some action that only one of the types of users can run, you do...

```
if(Yii::app()->user->getState('type') === 'W') {
    // Action of the Worker
} else {
    // Exception
}
```

If you need something more professional, you can control access to your site, through extension [Yii Rights](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/) or [Yii SRBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/srbac/) and use the best for your case.

Comment: Once you set a state, you can use `Yii::app()->user->type` to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I'd used this wiki for my small project:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac/

This is more functional module:
https://github.com/thyseus/yii-user-management

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the best (it depends, I guess) but here's a good one I have used in one of my projects. [yii-user](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user) .